# How to store related records in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a number of associated records such as below.

Parent records

{

```
_id:234,
title: "title1",
name: "name1",
association:"assoc1"
```

},

Child record

{

```
_id:21,
title: "child title",
name: "child name1",
```

},

I want to store such records into MongoDb. Can anyone help?

Regards.

Comment: What is your use case for these records? Mongodb is not a relational database and schemas should be built around you planned use of the data. Without knowing more I would suggest storing the parent ID in the child as a separate field, but would need to know more to give a real recommendation.

Comment: Please read this which discusses many different options for modeling in MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/ Then, if you still have a question come back and edit your question (and you'll need to provide more detail about your programming question than you have).

Comment: Discussions about managing relationships in NoSQL are a google search away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even MongoDB doesn't support joins, you can organize data in several different ways:

1) First of all, you can **inline**(or embed) related documents. This case is useful, if you have some hierarchy of document, e.g. post and comments. In this case you can like so:

```
{
    _id: <post_id>,
    title: 'asdf',
    text: 'asdf asdf',
    comments: [
    {<comment #1>},
    {<comment #2>},
    ...
    ]
}
```

In this case, all related data will be in the save document. You can fetch it by one query, but pushing new comments to post cause moving this document on disk, frequent updates will increase disk load and space usage.

2) **referencing** is other technique you can use: in each document, you can put special field that contains **_id** of parent/related object:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    type: 'post',
    title: 'asdf',
    text: 'asdf asdf'
},
{
    _id:2
    type: 'comment',
    text: 'yep!',
    parent_id: 1
}
```

In this case you store posts and comments in same collection, therefor you have to store additional field **type**. MongoDB doesn't support constraints or any other way to check data constancy. This means that if you delete post with _id=1, comments with _id=2 store broken link in **parent_id**.

You can separate posts from comments in different collections or even databases by using [database references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/), see your driver documentation for more details.

Both solutions can store tree-structured date, but in different way.